# PhoneGap/iOS - How to get Childbrowser to ignore links to Appstore?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have an app in the process of upgrading to the iOS5 SDK and Phonegap 1.0.0

The Childbrowser plugin is working properly, but when a link to the iTunes app store is clicked - the link is opened in a Childbrowser window.

I would prefer it to open in Appstore directly, which is what happens if I do not use the ChildBrowser plugin.

This is the appstore link (points to a submit a review page within the appstore)

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=386470812&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8

and this is how AppDelegate is modified

AppDelegate.m, scroll way down and replace the following:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}
```

with this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:
(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
NSURL *url = [request URL];
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"gap"] || [url isFileURL]) {
return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request
navigationType:navigationType ];
}
else {
ChildBrowserViewController* childBrowser =
[ [ ChildBrowserViewController alloc ] initWithScale:FALSE ];
[super.viewController presentModalViewController:childBrowser
animated:YES ];
[childBrowser loadURL:[url description]];
[childBrowser release];
return NO;
}
}
```

I used the method outlined in this blogpost to get the Childbrowser up and running
http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/installing-childbrowser-into-xcode-4-with-phonegap-1-0-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

Any thoughts on how to change this to produce the desired action?

Many thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether your URL contain http://itunes.apple.com/ as a substring by using `rangeOfString:` method and `location` attribute.
Please confirm your javascript called the url like this,

```
window.location="http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/code-check-basic-free-medical/id386470812?mt=8";
```

or you can use any jquery method.
Please replace `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method with the following snippet.

```
/**
 * Start Loading Request
 * This is where most of the magic happens... We take the request(s) and process the response.
 * From here we can re direct links and other protocalls to different internal methods.
 */
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:
(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  NSURL *url = [request URL];
  if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"gap"] || [url isFileURL]) {
    return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request
            navigationType:navigationType ];
  }
  else {
    //here we will check whether urlString has http://itunes.apple.com/ as substring or not
    NSString* urlString=[url absoluteString];
    if ([urlString rangeOfString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/"].location == NSNotFound){
      ChildBrowserViewController* childBrowser = [ [ ChildBrowserViewController alloc ] initWithScale:FALSE ];
      childBrowser.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
      childBrowser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;   
      [super.viewController presentModalViewController:childBrowser animated:YES ];   
      [childBrowser loadURL:urlString];
      [childBrowser release];
      return NO;      
    }
    else 
      return YES;      
  }
}
```

thanks,
Mayur